# Переменные в рекурсии (алгоритм quick sort)

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия, qsort

Реализую алгоритм быстрой сортировки на Python:

```
def partition(lines, l, r):
    x = lines[l]
    j = l
    for i in range(l + 1, r):
        if lines[i] <= x:
            j += 1
            lines[j], lines[i] = lines[i], lines[j]
    lines[l], lines[j] = lines[j], lines[l]
    return j

def quick_sort(lines, l, r):
    if l >= r:
        return lines
    m = partition(lines, l, r)
    quick_sort(lines, l, m - 1)
    quick_sort(lines, m + 1, r)
```

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Первый вызов функции partition правильно определяет индекс опорного пункта, дальше сортируем массивы слева и справа от него. Проблема в том, что переменная m, которая хранит индекс опорного пункта, изменяется после рекурсивного вызова quick_sort для левого массива, в результате чего когда вызывается quick_sort(lines, m + 1, r) границы правового массива уже потеряны.

Как сохранить значение переменной в рекурсивной функции?

Comment: *переменная m изменяется после рекурсивного вызова quick_sort* - кто ее меняет?

Comment: вынести переменную вне функции

Comment: переменная меняется при каждом вызове функции partition, а она вызывается при каждом вызове функции quick_sort. отсюда и проблема

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, тут проблема не в области видимости переменных, а в том, что m присваивается каждый раз при рекурсивном вызове функции. если сохранить нужное значение в какой-то глобальной переменной, необходимо прописать, при каких условиях его использовать, и как это прописать я как раз не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

Ошибся в предположении. Дело оказалось не в переменной m, а в неправильных параметрах вызова функции partition. Взял их из псевдокода реализации алгоритма, но не учел, что в Python range считает до параметра stop не включая. Вот так все работает:

```
def quick_sort(lines, l, r):
    if l >= r:
        return lines
    m = partition(lines, l, r)
    quick_sort(lines, l, m)        # ошибка была здесь
    quick_sort(lines, m + 1, r)
    return lines
```